# Unable to add multiple Ingresses with same host on nginx-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to add multiple Ingresses which should share the same host.
One Ingress should handle requests to www.example.de/some and the one all other requests.

Here is a snipped with the Ingress configurations

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "www.example.de"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/some"
        backend:
          serviceName: some-svc
          servicePort: 8585
```

---

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: other-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "www.example.de"
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: other-svc
          servicePort: 8080
```

As an ingress-controller I installed the `nginx-stable/nginx-ingress` via Helm

```
helm install my-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress
```

When attempting to create the two Ingresses from above only one is working when trying to access www.example.de (this is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts).

In the nginx-ingress log is see the following warnings:

> 2020/01/08 09:33:51 [warn] 560#560: conflicting server name "www.example.de" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
>
> 2020/01/08 09:33:51 [warn] 560#560: conflicting server name "www.example.de" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that I was using the wrong `nginx-ingress` controller. The [`nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress`](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) controller does not support merging Ingress rules with the same host (only via [Mergeable Ingresses](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/mergeable-ingress-types)).

Instead the [`kubernetes/ingress-nginx`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) should be used.
The differences between these controllers are listed [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/intro/nginx-ingress-controllers/).

Deleting the old controller and installing `kubernetes/ingress-nginx` instead using the following command fixed the problem.

```
helm install my-nginx stable/nginx-ingress
```

See https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm

Answer (score 4):

Just to compliment Brass' reply by referring to [the docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/):

> If multiple Ingresses define different paths for the same host, the ingress controller will merge the definitions.